# Yii2 - fucntions in controller or model

Tags: model-view-controller, yii2

I have such function in the controller

```
public function actionNext(){
    $category = $this->getCategory();
    $not_finished = $this->getQuestionFromCategory($category);
    if(!empty($not_finished)){
        $next_question_id = getNextQuestionId();
        $this->updateNextQuestion();
    }
    else{
        addNextCategory();

    }
}
```

My question is: all fuctions

- getCategory
- getQuestionFromCategory
- getNextQuestionId
- updateNextQuestion
- addNextCategory

from the example should be in model or controller too (all functions is the requests to the db).

Comment: Question and Category sounds like model objects. Create those classes (derived from Model or ActiveRecord) and add those functions there.

Comment: Questions like this aren't following SO rules btw.

Answer (score 0):

Normally the function related to the db are in model, tipically the model extend the active record and for this contain also the related sql/schema/model related function. in your case is think the function `getCategory` and probably `getQuestionFormCategory`

The function related to service for support controller action are place in controller. in your case  `genNextQuestionId`, `updateNewQuestion`, `addNextQuestion`.

The main rules is:  what's regarding the structural knwoledge of an entity is in model, what's regarding tactical behaviuor is in controller.

Obviously the part related to sort and find  are placed in ...search class.

Comment: It depends on how big this section of the site is. Technically you would separate db an validation in one model, helpers in another model, and so on. then the code to delegate between view and models in your controller. Such as QuestionModel and QuestionHelperModel. However, for just a few functions, they can all go in one, ie: QuestionModel. This is where you would create your own module with it's own views, multiples models, controller..